# Can Analytic Functions on the Circle be Characterized by Sobolev Norms?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis, analyticity

In Exercise I.4.4 of Katznelson's book *An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis* we learn that the Fourier series $$f(z) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} f_k z^k$$ defines an analytic function in the neighborhood of the unit circle if and only if there are constants $A_f , \alpha_f>0$ so that $$|f_k| \leq A_f e^{ -  \alpha_f |k|}.$$  In Chapter 7, Katznelson mentions that the compactness of the circle makes this characterization much simpler than the non-compact case of real line and the Paley-Wiener theorem.

To the question at hand: the exponential decay above implies that the $L^2$ Sobolev norms

$$||f||_s = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^{2s} |f_k|^2 \leq (2s)! A_f B_f^{2s}$$

of regularity $s=0,\tfrac{1}{2}, 1, \tfrac{3}{2}, 2, \ldots$ can all be bounded as above using some constants $A_f, B_f$.  For the implication, one plugs the first inequality into the expression for the Sobolev norm and uses geometric series to get $B_f = (1 - e^{-2\alpha_f})^{-1}$.  Notice that the radius $B_f$ goes to infinity as $\alpha_f \rightarrow 0$ as expected.

Question: is the converse true?  That is, can we characterize the analytic $f$ among all smooth $f$ as being exactly those for which the sequence of Sobolev norms admits a bound $||f||_{s} \leq (2s)! A_f B_f^{2s}$ for all $s$?

Comment: No. For the converse you need to look at the $B_h^{2s}(c)$ you obtain when $h_k(c) = e^{-c |k|}$ and ask that $\forall s, B_f^{2s} < A B_h^{2s}(c)$ for some $c,A$

Comment: Since the circle is compact that $f$ is analytic on some neighborhood of each point of the circle implies it is analytic on some annulus. For the real line it is different as $\frac{1}{1-e^{2i \pi z} e^{1/(z+1)^2}}$ is analytic on some neighborhood of the real line but not on $Im(z) \in (-r,r)$  for any $r$

Comment: Thank you for your message I agree with your second comment about circle vs. real line case.  I would like to know more about your first comment.  Are you saying that yes there is some way of modifying what I originally wrote to get a converse, I just had to include a multiplicative constant A?